# Unnecessary double quotes added to rows of CVS file when opening with notepad/notepad++

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, csv, opencsv

I am creating a CSV file using openCsv jar. If I am opening generated CSV file in spreadsheet then its fine. But same if I open with notepad/Notepad++ then its adding extra double inverted comma in each row.

Any help how can I fix that?

Comment: Double quotes around strings are part of the CSV format. Double-double quotes are how quotes are frequently escaped in CSV files (e.g. `1,2,3,"a ""quoted"" string"`). I'd imagine you just have to tell your CSV writer to not produce quoted strings.

Comment: this is how i am reading in spreadsheet, but with notepad its:
"0000001001||3|BBB - SHEA BODY BUTTER 200ML||687000.0|229000.0||38057|BBB - SHEA BODY BUTTER 200ML||112010278|0000001001|8796158590980|1145000.0|1145000.0|1145000.0||0.0|Amit KUmar|madhapur|21321|SARILAMAK|SUMATERA BARAT|Indonesia|3242343243||amit.ncet@gmail.com|||Thu Apr 24 11:07:19 IST 2014||DEBITBCA||1145000.0|||6|140000001001|DEBITBCA||||||24/04/2014 12:42:24"

Comment: extra double quotes added in beginning and end .

Comment: Yes, we have already established that you are confused by how CSV files are formatted. Again, if you don't want the quotes, see if you can turn off quoted strings in your CSV writer. They're part of CSV. I presume you read the wikipedia link that was posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a bug, that is the escaping of quotes.

[Definition of CSV File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)