# Pandas exported CSV file not enclosing text/string in double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a python script which gets a JSON file from a MongoDB database, performs ETL processes such as filtering, flattening the dictionary and finally exporting the dataframe to CSV (which works fine).

The issue I am having is when I open the CSV in Notepad, the text columns are not enclosed in quotation marks.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe when a datatype of a column has been specified as a string/text, when you open that file in Excel there are no quotes but when opened in Notepad it should show those string columns within quotes.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import json

mongo_client = MongoClient("XXXX")
db = mongo_client.rfqdb 
table = db.request
document = table.find({'createdAt': {'$gt': datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)}}) 
docs = list(document)
docs = json.dumps(docs,default=str)
docs = docs.replace(r"\n",'').replace(r"\r\n",'').replace(r"\r",'')
docs = json.loads(docs)
docs = json_normalize(docs)
docs = docs[["id","reportName"]].astype("string")
print(docs.dtypes)
```

```
id                          string
reportName                  string
```

When I open the exported CSV file from Pandas in Notepad++ it doesn't show the string within quotes:

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this situation as I've done this same process in Azure Data Factory where I have mapped these two columns as Strings and when I open the CSV in Notepad it shows the strings wrapped inside quotes(see below), so I'm a bit confused why Python Pandas isn't showing this when exporting.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the answered here, it is about how the CSV are formatted.
[Unnecessary double quotes added to rows of CVS file when opening with notepad/notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262569/unnecessary-double-quotes-added-to-rows-of-cvs-file-when-opening-with-notepad-no)

So, if you want to get rid of the double quotes I suggest to try this one:

```
csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: My issue isn't why I'm getting unnecessary double quotes, rather it's why am I not getting double quotes around my string/text columns e.g. the screenshot of how the column looks like when exported from Azure Data Factory. That's how it's supposed to be formatted when it's a string/text

Comment: Pardon me, just change the `csv.QUOTE_NONE` with `csv.QUOTE_ALL`
Its **Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.** as explained in [python-csv-quote-all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL)

or `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` can be used, if you don't want to double quotes the numeric data.

Comment: I think QUOTE_NONNUMERIC works better, but the problem with that is it even quotes the column headers which I don't need it to do

Comment: Have you tried to write the header first with fieldname, then you can input .json data to the `writerow`?
`fieldnames = ['id', 'reportName']`
`writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC )`
`writer.writeheader()`

Comment: have you got an example or somewhere where this is shown in the documentation as I haven't seen this been done before

Comment: [python-csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)
See the short usage example.